# Fibonacci web service with WAI

Tags: http, haskell, haskell-wai

I'm trying to write a simple Fibonacci web server using WAI but I just can't figure out the types.  This code is the essence of what I want to do, but it's broken.  The `getQueryArg` function returns a `Maybe ByteString` and I want to use that in my `fibHandler` function.

1. How do I correctly handle the `Maybe` in my `fibHandler`?
2. How do I call putStrLn on a Maybe? I'm trying `fmap` but I can't seem to get it right.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Wai
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 ()  -- Just for an orphan instance
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Data.Conduit
import Data.String.Utils
import Data.ByteString as BS (ByteString, putStrLn)
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as B (unpack)
import Data.Text as T (intercalate, pack, unpack)

app :: Application
app req
    | rawPathInfo req == "/fib" = fibHandler req
    | otherwise = notFoundHandler

fibHandler :: Request -> ResourceT IO Response
fibHandler req = do
    let nStr = getQueryArg (queryString req) "n"
    fmap (liftIO . BS.putStrLn) n
    let n = read nStr
    return $ responseLBS
        status200
        [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
        (show $ fib n)

fib :: Int -> Int
fib n = foldl (*) 1 [1..n]

getQueryArg :: Query -> BS.ByteString -> Maybe BS.ByteString
getQueryArg [] key = Nothing
getQueryArg ((k,v):qs) key
    | k == key = Just v
    | otherwise = getQueryArg qs key

notFoundHandler :: ResourceT IO Response
notFoundHandler = return $ responseLBS
    status404
    [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
    "Not found"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    BS.putStrLn $ "http://localhost:8080/"
    run 8080 $ app
```

[Update: a working copy of this code is here: https://gist.github.com/3145317]

Comment: In what way is this broken? You've mentioned how you'd like it improved (handle `Maybe`..) but not what's broken with the current code...

Comment: Just a note: `fib n = foldl (*) 1 [1..n]` is the factorial, not the Fibonacci number.

Comment: @sarnold it is broken because it doesn't handle Maybe from `getQueryArg`.  @DanielFischer yup you are totally right, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest thing to do with `Maybe` values is to use `case`.

```
case getQueryArg foo bar of
    Nothing -> {- something went wrong, write some code to report an error -}
    Just x  -> {- everything went okay, and x is the result of the successful computation -}
```

Once you've done this a couple dozen times, you can graduate to the shorthand versions:

```
maybe ({- went wrong -}) (\x -> {- successful x -}) (getQueryArg foo bar)
fromMaybe {- default value -} (getQueryArg foo bar)
traverse_ B.putStrLn (getQueryArg foo bar) -- this trick is a personal favorite
```